# How to using the fetch data outside the function with styled components?

Tags: javascript, typescript, themes, styled-components

I'm developing a webapp that renders css colors according to color data previously registered in an api. I was able to make this happen by storing the color data in cookies and putting it in a global component with style components.
It happens that when the user enters the application for the first time, the data that is in the cookies is not loaded along with the page, the colors only change from the second access onwards (the colors are already in the cookies)

My question would be: How would you make this page render only after the cookies are loaded OR how would you pass the data directly to the styled component object (something about using the fetch data outside the function)?

I'm new to the front-end, I accept suggestions for other approaches as well.

my themeClient.ts

```
// Função que peda os dados do cliente para preencher as cores
const getClientInfos = async () => {
    const ClientInfo = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/clientes/${cliente_id}/`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token_access}`,
        }
    })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
            // Passando as propriedades do tema para os cookies
            const cor_primaria = data["cor_primaria"]
            const cor_secundaria = data["cor_secundaria"]
            setCookie('cor_primaria', cor_primaria);
            setCookie('cor_secundaria', cor_secundaria)

            console.log('DADOS DA API getClientInfos: ', data)

        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))

    return ClientInfo
}
getClientInfos()

// Variáveis para cores do cliente
const cor_primaria = getCookies().cor_primaria;
const cor_secundaria = getCookies().cor_secundaria;

// Variáveis para tema
const branco = '#f5f5f5'
const primaryColor = decodeURIComponent(cor_primaria || '')
const secundaryColor = decodeURIComponent(cor_secundaria || '')


export default {
    title: 'themeClient',

    colors: {
        primary: primaryColor,
        secundary: secundaryColor,

        background: `linear-gradient( ${primaryColor}, ${secundaryColor})`,
        text: branco,
    }
};
```

my global.ts

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

export default createGlobalStyle`
    * {
        margin: 0;
        pedding: 0;
    }

    body {
        background: ${props => props.theme.colors.background };
        color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text };
       
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    aside {
        background: ${props => props.theme.colors.background };
        color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text };

        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    ul {
        background: ${props => props.theme.colors.background };
        color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text };

        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    div#navbar {
        background: ${props => props.theme.colors.background };
        color: ${props => props.theme.colors.text };

        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
`;
```

I tried to use localStorage too, but I believe that using storeges was not the best option.

Comment: Where is the definition of `getCookies()` coming from? If it's your code (or if you have access to the code) please post that as well.

Comment: i used ```setCookie()``` inside ```.then()``` in my fetch to send the data to the cookies, then i use ```getCookies()``` to collect and use the data

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer my question which, restated, is: where is getCookies() defined? Is this something you wrote or copied?

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm using next's `getCookies()` function. 
`import { getCookies, setCookie } from "cookies-next";`

Comment: I haven't worked with that package so this comment may not be helpfull. It looks like you'll want to use `getCookie()` - I can't find an example where they are using `getCookies()` the way you are - not to say that is shouldn't work they way you have coded. For example: `const cor_primaria = getCookie('cor_primaria');`. You may want to replace "cookies-next" with [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) (there are other documentation sites available than what I linked)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I believe the problem is happening because I'm saving the data in cookies, and that's why they can't be accessed right away on the first access. Is there another way to transport this hexadecimal data to the thema object without using storeges?